# Generic method for Selenium FindElement function

Tags: c#, selenium

So I created this generic find element function:

```
    public static IWebElement FindElement(IWebDriver driver, Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> expectedCondtions, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = CreateWebDriverWait(driver, finder,timeoutInSeconds);
        webDriverWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
        return webDriverWait.Until(expectedCondtions);
    }

    public static ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElements(IWebDriver driver, Func<IWebDriver, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>> expectedCondtions, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {           
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = CreateWebDriverWait(driver, finder, timeoutInSeconds);
        webDriverWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));            
        return webDriverWait.Until(expectedCondtions);
    } 

    private static WebDriverWait CreateWebDriverWait(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement finder, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
        webDriverWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
        return webDriverWait;
    }
```

Usage:

```
        IWebElement element=
            WaitAndFindElement(
            driver,
            ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("...")),
            120);
```

Now I wante to add the option to find `element` also not using `driver`.
For example instead of `driver.FindElement` i want to search for element from another `element`:

```
IWebElemen element = ...
element.FindElement...
```

So i want to change my function signature from:

```
IWebElement FindElement(IWebDriver driver,Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> expectedCondtions, int timeoutInSeconds)
```

To:

```
IWebElement FindElement(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement finder, Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> expectedCondtions, int timeoutInSeconds)
```

If `finder` is null i want to search using `driver.FindElement`.
Otherwise: `finder.FindElement`

So my question is how to accomplish that ?

Comment: Do you need Driver in the second scenario? Sounds to me like it is one or the other, Is this correct?

Comment: Why create a wrapper for the simple Selenium functions? What does this accomplish? You can do most of this in one or two lines anyway. You are also creating a new instance of `WebDriverWait` each time you call your function even if it's using the same timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Class WebElementFinder
{
   public static IWebElement FindElement(ISearchContext sc, By locator, Func<IWebElement, bool> elementCondition = null, int timeOutInceconds = 20)
        {
            DefaultWait<ISearchContext> wait = new DefaultWait<ISearchContext>(sc);
            wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOutInceconds);
            wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
            wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));

            return  wait.Until(x => GetElement(x, locator, elementCondition));
        }

        private static IWebElement GetElement(ISearchContext sc, By locator, Func<IWebElement, bool> elementCondition = null)
        {
             IWebElement webElement = sc.FindElement(locator);
             if(elementCondition != null)
            {
                if (elementCondition(webElement))
                    return webElement;
                else
                    return null;
            }
             else
            {
                return webElement;
            }
        }
}
```

Usage :

```
 Func<IWebElement, bool> isElementVisible = (webElement) => webElement.Displayed;
            var element = FindElement(driver, By.Id("name_10"), isElementVisible);
```

Comment: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/SearchContext.html

Answer (score 0):

This is good: I've had a similar case at work and this is what i did in C#:

```
IWebElement FindElement(IWebDriver driver, Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> expectedCondtions, int timeoutInSeconds, IWebElement finder = null)
```

This means that the default value for "finder" is null, and you can call your function with or without specifying it. ( You can add this parameter with default value to all of your methods)

Then you can simple do a simple if statement in your function to determine how to find the element.

```
if(finder != null)
{
    //use finder instead of driver and return
}
//Otherwise use driver
```

Comment: Yes but how can i use this finder instead of driver inside my functions ? can i have code example please ?

Comment: I ask it because i did not see any mention of driver.FindElement in my functions

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to make it complicate if you want to make it generic.
Here is the code that will solve the problem

```
Class WebElementFinder
{
 private static IWebElement FindElement(ISearchContext sc, By locator, int timeOutInceconds = 20)
        {
            DefaultWait<ISearchContext> wait = new DefaultWait<ISearchContext>(sc);
            wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOutInceconds);
            wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
            return wait.Until(x => GetElement(x, locator));
        }

        private static IWebElement GetElement(ISearchContext sc, By locator)
        {
           return sc.FindElement(locator);
        }
}
```

Let me explain some part of this code that will help you to understand the problem with the code you mentioned.

1. If you use webdriver wait then it is drived from DefaultWait class which takes IWebDriver into generic type. Hence untill method will have restriction to use driver object.
2. If you use Func in method then every calling method needs to create function for find element. However you can use it as an optional paramenter.

Now coming back to my code snippet.
I have Used DefaultWait that can be used for WebDriver as well as IWebElement. Both are drived from ISearchContext. 
Locator will help the find web element on driver/ IWebElement object as you asked in your post

Comment: And what about using expectedCondtions ?

Comment: because i looks for different expectedCondtions  on each web element (clickable, presence...)

Comment: You can write modify method with one more argument ..                                                      private static IWebElement FindElement(ISearchContext sc, By locator, Func<IWebElement, bool> elementCondition = null, int timeOutInceconds = 20)....You can pass delegate with condition you want to validate on found web element.

Comment: Can i have code example and usage ? (i never hear about ISearchContext )